# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type... (React Hook Form) (TypeScript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I have typescript interface with answers:

```
interface IAnswers { answer1: string; answer2: string ... }
```

and want to set value using react hook form:

```
setValue(`answer${data.id}`, 'Answer value')
```

`data.id` is number with question id, but i got

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"answer1" | "answer2" | "answer3"...
```

Comment: Is setValue is expecting type of IAnswers ? if yes then error is what it says

Answer (score 0):

You should use more specific type:

```
setValue(`answer${data.id}` as const, 'Answer value')
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you try like this;

```
import React from 'react'

interface IAnswers {
    answer1?: string,
    answer2?: string,
}

const TestComponent = () => {

    const [answers, setAnswers] = React.useState<IAnswers>({});

    const addAnswer = (id: string | number, value: string) => {

        const key = `answer${id}`;

        setAnswers({
            ...answers,
            [key]: value
        })

    }


    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default TestComponent
```